# Linq - Find max value from a nvarchar type column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

In my SQL Server column I have values like below.

```
3.2.31
5.6.81
8.0.3521
25
```

When I try to get the `MAX` value using LINQ instead of 25 I am getting 8.0.3521. Below is my LINQ query.

```
var maxCode = InventoryDB.Products.where(p => p.Name == "Reva Health").select( m => m.Code).Max();
```

The column type of Code is `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code in C#. Following the assumption those values are strings:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Linq
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>()
            {
                "3.2.31",
                "5.6.81",
                "8.0.3521",
                "25"
            };

            var doubleList = listOfStrings.ToList()
                .Select(y => y.Contains(".") ? 
                    Convert.ToDouble(y.Split(".").FirstOrDefault()) : 
                    Convert.ToDouble(y))
                .OrderByDescending(x => x);

            foreach(var member in doubleList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(member);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Note I .ToList() the IEnumerable thinking you might use this code. You want to grab data from your entityframework object prior to making these linq statements so it is not generating unwanted SQL.

Comment: This query will not work for Linq-to-SQL because it cannot translate the `string.Split` method.  And it's a bad idea to just pull everything into memory as there could eventually be many entries to deal with.

Comment: @juharr if you run the ToList() method against after your where clause. it will invoked the Linq-to-Sql. At that point, the following statements will not be evaluated to SQL to my understanding.

Comment: And if you want to suggest pulling it to memory you should use `AsEnumerable` to avoid creating an intermediate list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a string, not a number.  This is difficult to handle in SQL Server.  The following might be good enough:

```
select top (1) col
from t
order by try_convert(int, left(col, charindex('.', col) - 1)) desc,
         col desc;
```

This version is not perfect.  It orders by number before the first period, which is sufficient for the data in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below expression:

```
var maxCode = InventoryDB.Products.where(p => p.Name == "Reva Health")
.Select(l => new { 
                  s=Int32.Parse(l.Code.Substring(0,l.Code.IndexOf('.')!=-1?l.Code.IndexOf('.'):l.Code.Length)) 
                  })
.Max(i=>i.s);
```

Comment: I got this error - LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: it just for parse string to int you can use `Convert.ToInt32()` or `int.Parse()` as per your system configuration